# How to enforce file-scoped namespaces with StyleCop

Tags: c#, namespaces, stylecop

I want this

```
namespace SampleCode
{
    public class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

to become this

```
namespace SampleCode;

public class MyClass
{
}
```

with the help of StyleCop.

Is there any standard or custom rule for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the .editorconfig file, add the following rule

```ini
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:error
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0160-ide0161